# Prime number checker unbelievably slow

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, primes

I have this piece of code which checks whether a given number is prime:

```
If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
    Return False
End If
For i = 3 To x / 2 + 1 Step 2
    If x Mod i = 0 Then
        Return False
    End If
Next
Return True
```

I only use it for numbers `1E7 <= x <= 2E7`. However, it is extremely slow - I can hardly check 300 numbers a second, so checking all `x`'s would take more than 23 days...

Could someone give some improvements tips or say what I might be doing redundantly this way?

Comment: For a start, you only need to test up to `sqrt(x)`, not `x/2+1`.

Comment: Will that be faster? `sqrt(x)` would take more time to calculate I guess.

Comment: `i` only needs to go until `sqrt(x)` (note that you only need to compute the square root once, not every iteration of the loop, so it will be faster), not `x / 2`. That should allow you to test that range a lot faster, but even more faster is the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: firt line has error - you've write `i` instead of `x`

Comment: Just edited that - I'm sorry.

Comment: 2 is a prime number and your code returns `false` when `x` is 2.

Comment: True, but as I said I only use specific input values in which 2 is not apparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely change your algorithm! You can try [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or a more advanced [Fermat primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test). Beware that your code will be more complicated, as you would need to implement modular arithmetics. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) for the list of some even more mathematically advanced methods.

Answer (score 6):

That is general algorithm for checking prime number. 
If you want to check prime number in bulk use algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 4):

Look up the term "Sieve of Eratosthenes". It's a two thousand years old algorithm which is way better than yours. It's often taught in school.

Answer (score 3):

You can also look for  [AKS primality test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)
This is a good algorithm for checking primality.

Answer (score 1):

Since `x/2 + 1` is a constant through out the looping operation, keep it in a separate variable before the `For` loop. Thus, saving a **division & addition** operation every time you loop. Though this might slightly increase the performance.

Comment: I think compiler should optimize this case

Comment: Should compiler do that too. I didn't knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to create a `Set` that contains all the prime numbers up to the largest number you need to check. It will take a while to set up the `Set`, but then checking if a number exists in it will be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Split range in some chunks, and do checks in two or more threads, if you have multicore cpu. Or use `Parallel.For`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I seem to be using a very inefficient algorithm - so I won't use mine anyway.

Comment: I would change the language to a faster one before doing parallelism in VB.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the number is prime you have only check if it can't be divided by primes less then it.

Please check following snippet:

```
 Sub Main()

        Dim primes As New List(Of Integer)
        primes.Add(1)

        For x As Integer = 1 To 1000
            If IsPrime(x, primes) Then
                primes.Add(x)
                Console.WriteLine(x)
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Function IsPrime(x As Integer, primes As IEnumerable(Of Integer)) As Boolean
        For Each prime In primes
            If prime <> 1 AndAlso prime <> x Then
                If x Mod prime = 0 Then
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that will save a lot of time, mostly because the primes only have to be calculated once. However, I see that another algotihm exists which is much faster.

Comment: only primes no greater then `sqrt(x)` should be checked against. The code as written will be very slow still - quadratic, instead of `~< k^1.5`, for `k` primes produced. The OP code is only `~ k^2 * log(k)`. The `log` speedup is about 15x (23 days => 1.5 days), but `sqrt` is about 800x more (=> 3 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

it slow because you use the x/2. I modified your code a little bit. (I don't know about syntax of VB, Maybe you have to change my syntax.)

```
If x < 2 Then
    Return False
IF x == 2 Then
    Return True
If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
    Return False
End If
For i = 3 To (i*i)<=x Step 2
    If x Mod i = 0 Then
        Return False
    End If
Next
Return True
```